# How to insert data from R into Oracle table with identity column?

Tags: r, oracle, insert

Assume I have a simple table in Oracle db

```
CREATE TABLE schema.d_test
(
    id_record integer GENERATED AS IDENTITY START WITH 95000 NOT NULL,
    DT DATE NOT NULL,
    var varchar(50),
    num float,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_RECORD)
)
```

And I have a dataframe in R

```
dt = c('2022-01-01', '2005-04-01', '2011-10-02')
var = c('sgdsg', 'hjhgjg', 'rurtur')
num = c(165, 1658.5, 8978.12354)

data = data.frame(dt, var, num)%>% 
  mutate(dt = as.Date(dt))
```

I'm trying to insert `data` into Oracle `d_test` table using the code

```
data %>% 
  dbWriteTable(
    oracle_con,
    value = .,
    date = T,
    'D_TEST',
    append = T,
    row.names=F,
    overwrite = F
  )
```

But the following error returned

```
Error in .oci.WriteTable(conn, name, value, row.names = row.names, overwrite = overwrite,  : 
  Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt, data = value) : 
  ORA-00947: not enough values
```

What's the problem?
How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: This could be relevant : https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/59. Not sure how this impacts Oracle DB, but you could try to add  `id_record` filled with `NA`s to the dataframe you pass to `dbWriteTable`

Answer (score 0):

This is pure Oracle (I don't know R).

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test_so (id number generated always as identity not null, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_so(name) values ('Name 1');

1 row created.
```

My initial idea was to suggest you to insert *any value* into the ID column, hoping that Oracle would discard it and generate its own value. However, that won't work.

```
SQL> insert into test_so (id, name) values (-100, 'Name 2');
insert into test_so (id, name) values (-100, 'Name 2')
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

---

But, if you can afford **recreating** the table so that it doesn't automatically generate the ID column's value but use a "workaround" (we used anyway, as identity columns are *relatively* new in Oracle) - a sequence and a trigger - you might be able to "fix" it.

```
SQL> drop table test_so;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test_so (id number not null, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_so;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_so
  2    before insert on test_so
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := seq_so.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Inserting only `name` (Oracle will use a trigger to populate `ID`):

```
SQL> insert into test_so(name) values ('Name 1');

1 row created.
```

This is what you'll do in your code - provide *dummy* `ID` value, just to avoid

> ORA-00947: not enough values

error you have now. Trigger will *discard* it and use sequence anyway:

```
SQL> insert into test_so (id, name) values (-100, 'Name 2');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_so;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Name 1
         2 Name 2       --> this is a row which was supposed to have ID = -100

SQL>
```

Comment: @littefoot unfortunately this version doesn't work with `dbWriteTable` in R.

Comment: Sorry, Davit ... as I said, I don't know R. I hoped that such a workaround would help.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can handle this problem is to create table with `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY`  like this

```
CREATE TABLE CM_RISK.d_test
(
    id_record integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY START WITH 5000 NOT NULL ,
    DT date NOT NULL,
    var varchar(50),
    num float,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_RECORD)
)
```